# Como retornar todos os parcelamentos nessa função em [PHP]?

Tags: php, array

Boa noite pessoal. Estou preso num impasse que não consigo resolver. Eu preciso retornar 11 vezes `$tot_formatado` que corresponde a exatamente uma vez para cada taxa de parcelamento presente dentro do array.

Se repararem no `$tot_formatado`, coloquei lá `$array[0]` que me retorna o preço para o `$array[0]` que corresponde ao `$parc_two` que é de ***0.055***.

Precisa retornar os 11 valores referente cada um a cada indíce do array usado para o calculo. Exemplo no fundo.

```
function parcelamento ($valor){

        $taxa_intermediacao = 0.064; // porcentagem
        $taxa_processamento = 0.60; // monetário
        $array = array (
            $parc_two => 0.055, // porcentagem
            $parc_tree => 0.060, 
            $parc_four => 0.065, 
            $parc_five => 0.075, 
            $parc_six => 0.085, 
            $parc_seven => 0.095,
            $parc_eight => 0.105,
            $parc_nine => 0.115,
            $parc_ten => 0.125,
            $parc_eleven => 0.130,
            $parc_twelve => 0.135
        );

        $tot_formatado = number_format ( ( $valor - ( $valor * ( $array[0] + $taxa_intermediacao ) ) - 0.60 ), 2 );
        return $tot_formatado;

    }

    parcelamento($valor);
```

> **Acho que isso tem alguma relação com loop e arrays mas não sei ao certo como fazer.**

Answer (score 2):

Associe os valores no array, um em cada indice, em seguida efetue o cálculo para cada parcela e insira em um novo array:

```
function parcelamento ($valor){

$taxa_intermediacao = 0.064; // porcentagem
$taxa_processamento = 0.60; // monetário
$array = array (
    'parc_two' => 0.055, // porcentagem
    'parc_tree' => 0.060, 
    'parc_four' => 0.065, 
    'parc_five' => 0.075, 
    'parc_six' => 0.085, 
    'parc_seven' => 0.095,
    'parc_eight' => 0.105,
    'parc_nine' => 0.115,
    'parc_ten' => 0.125,
    'parc_eleven' => 0.130,
    'parc_twelve' => 0.135
);


 $tot_formatado = array();        
  foreach($array as $taxa){
        $tot_formatado[] = number_format ( ( $valor - ( $valor * ( $taxa + $taxa_intermediacao ) ) - 0.60 ), 2 );
    }

    return $tot_formatado;

}

$parcelas = parcelamento($valor);
foreach($parcelas as $parcela){
    echo 'Valor '.$parcela;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode retornar 11 valores de uma vez com o return, uma alternativa é calcular todas as parcelas em um array separado e retornar esse array, outra é colocar outro atributo na função que vai retornar o valor desejado.

Assim:

```
//via array
<?php
function parcelamento($valor) {

    $taxa_intermediacao = 0.064; // porcentagem
    $taxa_processamento = 0.60; // monetário
    $array = array (
        $parc_two => 0.055, // porcentagem
        $parc_tree => 0.060, 
        $parc_four => 0.065, 
        $parc_five => 0.075, 
        $parc_six => 0.085, 
        $parc_seven => 0.095,
        $parc_eight => 0.105,
        $parc_nine => 0.115,
        $parc_ten => 0.125,
        $parc_eleven => 0.130,
        $parc_twelve => 0.135
    );

    $tot_formatado = array();
    foreach($array as $parc) {

        $tot_formatado = number_format ( ( $valor - ( $valor * ( $parc + $taxa_intermediacao ) ) - 0.60 ), 2 );
    }

    return $tot_formatado;

}

$results = parcelamento($valor);
foreach($results as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Ou assim:

```
//via parametro
<?php
function parcelamento($valor, $parcela) {

    $taxa_intermediacao = 0.064; // porcentagem
    $taxa_processamento = 0.60; // monetário
    $array = array (
        $parc_two => 0.055, // porcentagem
        $parc_tree => 0.060, 
        $parc_four => 0.065, 
        $parc_five => 0.075, 
        $parc_six => 0.085, 
        $parc_seven => 0.095,
        $parc_eight => 0.105,
        $parc_nine => 0.115,
        $parc_ten => 0.125,
        $parc_eleven => 0.130,
        $parc_twelve => 0.135
    );

    $tot_formatado = number_format ( ( $valor - ( $valor * ( $array[$parcela] + $taxa_intermediacao ) ) - 0.60 ), 2 );
    return $tot_formatado;

}

echo parcelamento($valor, 0); // ou outra parcela $parc_two, etc...
//pode fazer um for para chamar outras parcelas
```